# ASP.NET MVC 4 LINQ join -> view

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I know this is something simple but I can't figure it out :(

I'm receiving this error:

The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[<>f__AnonymousType3`5[System.String,System.String,System.String,System.Nullable`1[System.DateTime],System.String]]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[MvcApplication3.Order]'.

Here is the code for my controller:

```
    var query = from o in db.Orders
                join c in db.Customers on o.CustomerID equals c.CustomerID
                where o.CustomerID == q
                select new
                {
                    o.CustomerID,
                    o.ShipAddress,
                    o.ShipCity,
                    o.ShippedDate,
                    c.ContactName
                };

    /*
    var query = from o in db.Orders
                where o.CustomerID == q
                select o;
    */
    return View(query.ToList());
```

Here is my view:

```
@model IEnumerable<MvcApplication3.Order>


@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Search";
}

<h2>Search</h2>
Your search results contains @Model.Count() rows

<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Customer ID</td>
        <td>Address</td>
        <td>City</td>
        <td>Shipped to Date</td>
    </tr>
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>@item.CustomerID</td>
        <td>@item.ShipAddress</td>
        <td>@item.ShipCity</td>
        <td>@item.ShippedDate</td>
        <td>@item.Customer.ContactName</td>

    </tr>
}
</table>
```

I'm assuming it has something to do with the way View is setup. If I remove the return View() and just loop through the data from the controller I get the results I expect. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:**

Try this:

```
select new Order()
                    {
                        CustomerId = o.CustomerID,
                        ShipAddress = o.ShipAddress,
                        ShipCity = o.ShipCity,
                        ShippedDate = o.ShippedDate,
                        Customer = new Customer()
                              {
                                 ContactName = c.ContactName
                              }
                    };
```

You didn't specify the model. You created a `List` of anonymous objects, and the view is expecting an `IEnumerable<Order>`.

Comment: if I put that in, I receive "Error 2 Cannot initialize type 'MvcApplication3.Order' with a collection initializer because it does not implement 'System.Collections.IEnumerable'

Comment: sorry, i didn't pay enough attention. Check my edit. Also replace `new Customer` with the model name for your `Customer` variable in the `Order` model.

Comment: Thank you. It's working. Would a ViewModel class file also help with this scenario?

Comment: It would help, but i prefer the MVCR pattern. Basically, you create another class called Repository, that manages the database. There i define methods like GetCustomers(), GetOrders(), DeleteCustomer(), etc. In the controller, i initialize the model, call the repository methods to fill the model with data and send it to view.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try just like this.

```
var query = (from o in db.Orders
                join c in db.Customers on o.CustomerID equals c.CustomerID
                where o.CustomerID == q
                select c);
```

and in view you can change it to

> @model IEnumerable < MvcApplication3.Customers >